# What is the most efficient way to implement HTTP Live Video Streaming in Android?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, exoplayer, mpeg-dash

For the past month I have been searching over the Internet for ways to implement recording live video from an application on Android and sending it over to a server, but the more I research the more confused I get.

First of all, I am looking for a streaming protocol that can be used for iOS also in the future, so I came to a conclusion that **DASH**(Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP) is the ideal solution. 
In addition, the recent Android framework, **ExoPlayer**, support this feature.
Furthermore, I do not wish to use a Live Streaming engine such as WOWZA.

Secondly, based on my research I also concluded that any HTTP server can be used to receive the "chuncks" of data, but I must have a streaming server to be able to stream the video back to the users. 
I believe this process is quite complex but I will not give up until I successfully make it work.

Lastly, my question is, what Server, Protocol should I use to be able to achieve this ? And how to convert video directly and send to server ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your questions re protocol and server:

- A 'streaming protocol that can be used for iOS also in the future'

It probably depends what you mean by 'future. At the moment apple require you to use HLS on iOS for any video on a Mobile Network (cellular) which is over 10 mins long. DASH is establishing itself as the industry standard so this may change and apple may accept it also, but if you need something in the near future you may want to plan to support DASH and HLS.

- What server should you use for streaming

Streaming video is complex and the domain is fast changing so it really is good to use or build on a dedicated streaming server, if you can. These will generally have mechanisms and/or well documented procedures for converting input videos to the different formats and bit rates you need, depending on the reach and user experience goals you have. Reach will determine the different encodings you need, different browsers and devices supporting different encodings, and if you want your user to have good experience avoiding buffering you will want multiple bit rate versions of each format also - this allows DASH and HLS provide Adaptive Bit rate Streaming (ABR) which means the clients can select the best bit rate at any given time depending on network conditions. Video manipulation, especially transcoding, is a CPU intensive task so another advantage of dedicated streaming server software is that it should be optimised as much as possible to reduce your server loads.

If you do decide to go the streaming server route, then there are open source alternatives, as well as Wowza which you mention above, such as:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org

These have plugins that support ABR etc - if you search for 'GStreamer streaming server ABR' you will find some good blogs about setting this up.